# Deshabilitar select una vez elegida la opcion

Tags: jquery

Hola tengo un select y necesito que una vez que se seleccione una opción se deshabiliten las otras opciones  para que el usuario no pueda elegir una distinta  aqui esta el select

```
 <div class='col-md-4' style="">
      <label>Seleccione Destino</label>
      <select class='form-control' name='destino' id='destino' >
       <option value="">Selecciona Area destino</option>
       <?php 

       $query_area=mysqli_query($conn,"select id_area, area from areas");
       while($rw=mysqli_fetch_array($query_area))  {

        ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $rw['id_area'];?>"><?php echo $rw['area']; $catera= $rw['id_area']; ?></option>


        <?php

      }
      ?>
    </select>
  </div>
```

y aqui esta el script ... me funciona al revés porque una vez seleccionado me deshabilita la opcion que deseo y me sigue permitiendo seleccionar otras

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    // Change es un evento que se ejecuta cada vez que se cambia el valor de un elemento (input, select, etc).
         $('#destino').change(function(e) {
         $('#idestino').val($(this).val());
         **$("#destino option:selected").attr('disabled','disabled');**
        })
         $('#comb1').change(function(e) {
         $('#Id_Tipo').val($(this).val());
        });
         $('#comb2').change(function(e) {
         $('#Id_Tipos').val($(this).val());
        });

      });
    </script>
```

// remarque la linea que deberia cambiar

Desde ya gracias

Comment: Y si deshabilitas todas las opciones y luego solo habilitas la seleccionada?

Comment: Gracias, lo solucione había un error en la linea que hago referencia al select, es solo (#destino).attr(......Muchas Gracias